# How to run a program using a python script in raspberrypi

Tags: python, scripting, debian, raspberry-pi

I know that i can just add the location and create a bash script. but I want to run a program (c or Java code). I tried using 'call' and 'execfile' but without success. please help me. I also want to print 'success' if it opens.

Comment: Also if you could include a code snippet of what it is you are trying to run. In bash you can do `./some_compiled_c_file` and when using bash with python you can `python some_python_file.py`

Comment: @jm_____ this question has been closed on raspberrypi.SE as it is by no means specific to the pi (and therefore off topic per rules). It is very generic and should be either answered here or nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import Popen,PIPE

proc = Popen(["/path/to/java_exe","/path/to/a.java"],stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)
stderr,stderr = proc.comunicate()
if proc.returncode == 0:
   print "SUCCESS?"
```

maybe ... its not really very clear what you are trying to do.